# Design stories with techniques from other creative processes

Tags: creative-writing, technique

I view all creative proccesses as design disciplines. Thus composers, architects, writers etc. all are designers from my point of view.

Could song rhythms be applied from design perspective to a story/plot/scenario to good use? And i'm not only talking about song rhythm, i'm talking about borrowing other-design specific practices and applying it to yours?

Comment: Could you maybe describe some of those practices to those of us that are not so familiar with composing music?

Comment: @Tannalein Imagine if your storyline main events tension could fallow a certain rhythm from a song. This has come to me because i was imagining certain plots or tails and had actually "background music" in my head for that certain plot.. and that left me thinking if i could "implant" the songs rhythm in my story.

Comment: I know a lot of writers that write to background music that best suits the plot, it puts them in the right mood. But think about this: some classical music was written to tell the story. Take Vivaldi's Spring from The Four Seasons. The first part is fast, it's trying to "show" a spring storm, the second one is the calm after the storm, and the third one is nature coming to life, with birds singing and flowers blooming and everything. The whole piece is telling the story of spring. I can imagine a three-act structure story following the same rhythm.

Comment: Please check [Superbrothers: Sword & Sworcery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superbrothers:_Sword_%26_Sworcery_EP). In this game, they use songs to create the very story.

Comment: I'm concerned this question is too broad and nebulous to be addressed in Q&A format. I think it'd make for a terrific forum discussion, but I'm not seeing an answerable question here. "Could song rhythms be applied to writing?" Sure, they _could_. It might be artificial. It might not work well. The problems could probably be fixed by a good writer. Or not. But the point is, nothing's stopping somebody from trying. "Can this be done?" Yeah, sure, why not- this isn't a question; it's an invitation to discussion about how and why and what would be cool. Great for a forum. Doesn't quite work here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on your point of view.  The creative process for any endeavor can withstand a great amount of tinkering and experimentation.  Taking the architecture example, as I read the question, you're asking "Can I take the process of building a building and use that to build a story, instead?"

Steps to Designing a Building:

1. Figure out what the building is for.  Your approach is going to be different if you're building a skyscraper or a gas station.  This step includes picking the right location, figuring out what your intended audience is, and figuring out if you have the infrastructure to support your building.
2. Identify key features you want to include or want to avoid. "Last place I worked the ceilings were too low, but we had this big open window I really liked..."
3. Broad strokes design.  "The building is going to be six stories with a roof patio.  We have good public transit access, so plan to provide minimal parking..."
4. Design the Structure.  At this point you figure out the structural supports, going the ground to the top of your building.  Where are the stairs, the elevators?  How are people going to move through the building?  A bunch of tiny little offices or big open spaces?  Where are the electrical risers and the wet-walls?
5. Design the floors.  Now you finally get to lay out the rooms.  This is the part most people think of and one of the least interesting in practice.  If your structure is built correctly, the rooms should be obvious.
6. Details.  Light fixtures, fire sprinklers, window molding...  Nothing takes a room from zero to finished quite like new lights and a coat of paint.

Throughout the process, you have to pay attention to changing situations.  Perhaps the client says he wanted bay windows, but now says he wants a modern look.  The city plans showed enough water for a six story building, but checking the pressure only reveals enough for five stories.  You'd planned to use a design detail on the first floor, but it worked so well you want to use it throughout as a unifying theme.  And so on.

These are the same steps you can use when telling any story.  What is my setting?  Who am I telling this story to?  What effect am I trying to achieve?  Where are my structural walls, i.e. what elements support my idea, providing structure and unification?

At the same time, the approach and the cadence is very different.  It would be an interesting experiment to approach writing a story in exactly this method.  And then again, but using the steps to painting a painting (choose a subject, mix your paints, prepare the canvas...).  I have been told many broadway composers work in teams, with one writing music and the other lyrics.  That would make for an interesting approach to writing.